# Why couldn't the duplicate cases be "divided out"?

Tags: combinatorics

> A group of 8 people is to be chosen from three countries, K, L, and M. K has 3 people, L has 4 people, and M has 5 people. What are the number of ways in which the group can be chosen if it includes at least 1 person from each country?

I understand that a solution is to take the complement through

**all possibilities - only K and M - only L and M = 12C8 - 8C8 - 9C8 = 485**

However, in my first attempt at this question, I took a more direct approach through

**1 from K x 1 from L x 1 from M x 5 from remaining = 3C1 x 4C1 x 5C1 x 9C5 = 7560**

This is clearly wrong as **all possibilities = 12C8 = 495**

I now understand and believe that this is wrong because it counts K1L1M1K2... and K2L1M1K1... as unique and different cases when they are the same. However, I tried to think of a add-on on my answer to "divide out" the duplicate cases. Intuitively to me, there should be and should be a multiple of 2. Yet, when you take 7560/485, it yields a non-whole number. Why is this so? Why can't I "divide out" the duplicates from 7560 to reach the answer of 485?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you chose K1L1M1 and then K2M2M3M4M5. This is $8$ people in total. You could interchange K1 with K2 and M1 with M2, M3, M4 or M5 in the sense that you described in your post. So this combination is counted $2\cdot4=8$ times.

Now suppose you chose K1L1M1 and then K2L2M2M3M4. You can interchange K1 with K2, L1 with L2, and M1 with M2, M3 or M4. So this combination is counted $2\cdot2\cdot3=12$ times.

As you see, different combinations are counted different number of times. So no wonder quotient $7560/485$ is not an integer.

Comment: No, you don’t need to calculate $2!\cdot5!$ because in your initial calculation you already used $9C5$ which dealt with overcounts in the second part of the group (the last five persons), so you can only interchange K1 with K2 and only M1 with any other single M.